# Visualforce page action method does not get invoked in force.com site

Tags: force.com-sites, visualforce

I am using a method is page's "action" attribute. When I am testing this by login into salesforce, it's working fine. But when I used this page on Force.com sites, the action method didn't execute every-time. Sometime it works and some time don't work.

Can anyone suggest why it's behaving like this ?

VF Page:

```
<apex:page sidebar="false" showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" applyHTMLTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" controller="APTS_eCommerceController"   action="{!setPrereqs}" >

</apex>
```

Controller :

```
public void setPrereqs(){
 CustomObject obj = new CustomObject();
insert obj;
}
```

Comment: Let me use my crystal ball to look at your code.

Comment: Wild Guess - Do you have the page & controller included in profile of the Force.com Site user? Check permissions on profile for Objects, fields etc which are being used in Page & Controller.

Comment: @Ganesh I have already provided all the permissions to the Guest User. As I have already mentioned that it's is not showing any error. Sometime it's working perfectly but sometime the action method didn't get called.

Comment: Are you rerendering a section of the page and swallowing error messages? I.e. not rerendering an apex:pagemessages component to show the errors?  You really need to post some code to give us a chance, otherwise this question is likely to be closed as too broad.

Comment: Please post some code to understand your problem better.

Comment: I have added the code

Comment: You can also put a debug log on the guest user. See if anything weird is occurring as well if you are not getting errors on your sites page.

Comment: I have already tried this. Debug logs are not showing debug statement sometimes and sometime it's showing

Comment: Is there any difference between the 2? E.g. different user, profile, browser? Maybe you can display the username on the screen, to check who is actually logged in.

Comment: @Guy Yes.. for sites, it is guest user

Comment: Yes but I was wondering if in some cases maybe your were logged in without realizing. E.g. when opening a new tab in an existing browser session where you were logged in to SF normally.. There has to be a difference between the attempts, it can't just randomly behave different..